# Programming error with order by and distinct on Django with PostgreSQL

Tags: python, django, postgresql

There are a lot of similar posts but none that hit exactly at what I am trying to get to.  I get that a distinct has to use the same fields as order_by, which is fine.

So I have the following query:

```
q = MyModel.objects.order_by('field1', 'field2', '-tstamp').distinct('field1', 'field2')
```

Ultimately I am trying to find the latest entry in the table for all combinations of `field1` and `field2`.  The `order_by` does what I think it should, and that's great.  But when I do the `distinct` I get the following error.

```
ProgrammingError: SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions
```

Ultimately this seems like a SQL problem (not a Django one).  However looking at the django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct) for distinct, it shows what can and can't work.  It does say that

```
q = MyModel.objects.order_by('field1', 'field2', '-tstamp').distinct('field1')
```

will work (...and it does).  But I don't understand that when I add on `field2` in the same order as done in the `order_by` I still get the same result.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

**EDIT:** I also notice that if I do

```
q = MyModel.objects.order_by('field1', 'field2', '-tstamp').distinct('field1', 'field2', 'tstamp') # with or without the - in the order_by
```

It still raises the same error, though the docs suggest this should work just fine

Comment: Since you don't show `MyModel`, can we assume `field1`, `field2` and `tstamp` are relatively ordinary fields (no ForeignKey or such)?

Comment: Your first example results in the error shown. Then, you say about your second example: "when I add on field2 in the same order as done in the order_by I still get the same result." With same result, do you mean the same *error* as for the first example? Or do you mean the (returned) result from second example?

Comment: It might be worth a try to show [what SQL Django generates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running).

Comment: @Evert they not ordinary fields.  When you mentioned that I tried ordering by and distincting by field1__pk and field2__pk.  Seems to work but want to make sure it's safe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to get the query to run properly by using pk's in the order_by()

```
q = MyModel.objects.order_by('field1__pk', 'field2__pk', '-tstamp').distinct('field1__pk', 'field2__pk')
```

Apparently when they are not ordinary types the orderby doesn't play super nice.  However using the pk's of the objects seems to work

Answer (score 0):

Test this one :

```
q = MyModel.objects.order_by('field1__id', 'field2__id', '-tstamp').distinct('field1__id', 'field2__id')
```